# How to show the subset $Y$ is closed discrete?

Tags: general-topology

The example is following:

Let $Y=\{(0,y):y \in R\}$. Let $E \subset R^2$, i.e., the subset of the real plane, and $E=Y\cup \{ (\frac 1n, \frac k{n^2}): n\in Z^+, k \in Z\}$. The topology on $E$ is this:

1. The point $(\frac 1n, \frac k{n^2})$ is open;
2. $\{U_n(y_0): n=1,2,...\}$ are the nbhds of the point $(0,y_0)$ of $Y$ is defined as following:
   $$U_n(y_0)=\{(x,y): x \le \frac 1n, |y-y_0|\le x\}$$.

My text book said $Y$ is closed discrete in $E$. I could see $Y$ is closed: for any point $y \in Y^C$, the set $\{y\}$ is open which is disjoint with $Y$. However, I fail to show that $Y$ is a discrete space.

Could anybody help me? Thanks ahead:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, if $(0,y) \in U_n(y_0)$ then we must have $| y - y_0 | \leq 0 \leq \frac{1}{n}$, and therefore $y = y_0$.  It follows that $U_n (y_0) \cap Y = \{ (0,y_0) \}$ for all $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: Mm, It seems so simple. Thanks for your answer.